# ODBC Library in R - getting "Data source name not found and no default driver specified" Error

Tags: r, odbc, dbi, rodbc

I have the driver working everything because i am using Power BI perfectly. I am switching to R for some of the calculations and now this error is creeping up

```
install.packages("odbc")

    library(odbc)

    con<- dbConnect(odbc::odbc(),
                     driver = "[Cloudera ODBC Driver for Apache Hive]",
                     host = "[Confidential]",
                     Schema = "[Confidential]",
                     user = ("Confidential"),
                     password = ("Confidential"),
                     port = 8443)
```

My ODBC connection is 64 bit

Is there a specific connection string that i need to use here?

Comment: I don't use `RODBC`, but I do use `odbc` and `DBI`, and nowhere have I seen brackets around the driver name. Have you tried `"Cloudera ..."` without the brackets? If you do install `odbc` for some reason, I know it has `odbc::odbcListDrivers()` which gives you the verbatim strings that can be used.

Comment: You're right, no need for brackets. It at least progressed to the next error where it says Unexpected response received from server. Please ensure the server host and port specified for the connection are correct and confirm if SSL should be enabled for the connection...but this is different from the previous one so thank you!

Comment: Port 8443 seems odd to me (while not reserved, it's commonly a redirected 443, the port for https). Are you certain that you're connecting to the database service? https://db.rstudio.com/databases/hive/ suggests that Hive's port is 10000.

Comment: I was just using the properties that i inputted in my ODBC Data Source Administrator (64 Bit) to connect to the Hive. Would the port that i input in R be different from it? Sorry, new to this.

Comment: Are you certain that you configured it right there? I don't know the correct answer for Hive because I don't use it, but I use ODBC daily. Obviously, if the port is wrong, no SSL/user/pass/driver combination is going to make it work. Can you verify that the ODBC connection as configured works via some non-R solution? From where did you learn to configure your base ODBC connection with port 8443?

Comment: Yes, that port works because i use Power BI daily to connect to the enterprise data lake. This was given to us by IT

Comment: Good. Next would be your connection. Your code here is not using the ODBC connection you set up in the ODBC Administration (windows?). If you want to use *that* configuration, you need to refer to it by-name instead of providing all of the configuration options here. For instance, if it is named `myhive` in your system ODBC config, try `con <- DBI::dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), dsn="myhive", UID="myuser", PWD="mypass")`. (This allows you to use the same SSL/... settings that you know are working for your Power BI connections.)

Comment: PERFECT. Got it into my R. Can you post your answer below and i will accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are four issues to consider here:

1. Originally, the driver had brackets around it, those needed to be removed.

   ```r
   # original
   con<- dbConnect(odbc::odbc(),
                   driver = "[Cloudera ODBC Driver for Apache Hive]", ...)
   # fixed
   con<- dbConnect(odbc::odbc(),
                   driver = "Cloudera ODBC Driver for Apache Hive", ...)
   ```
2. I suspect that the wrong labels `user=` and `password=` need to be changed. Per https://db.rstudio.com/databases/hive/, I think they should have been `UID=` and `PWD=`, respectively.
3. Since the connection error suggested connection-encryption (SSL) problems, then further arguments should be provided to `DBI::dbConnect` to set the correct options. I don't know what they are, to be honest, and I could not find documentation on what they are, so I ignored this problem. On to issue 4 ...
4. You said that you configured this within your *"ODBC Data Source Administrator (64 Bit)"*, which is a system-wide configuration for named connections, and that you use this configuration for Power BI (meaning that the connection there is good). In your code above, you are not using that system configuration, you are defining it from-scratch. Since the system configuration is known to work, you can use that instead of re-defining, as in

   ```r
   con <- DBI::dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), dsn = "myhive", UID = "myuser", PWD = "mypass")
   ```

   where `myhive` is the name you assigned the configuration within your ODBC data source administration.